# Condition based select and join queries

Tags: mysql

Query 1:

```
SELECT if(COUNT(0),1,0) as 'IsPresent'
FROM table1
WHERE Id=1500;
```

Query2:

If IsPresent is 1, then

```
select t2.mark,t2.age from table2  t2,table1 t1
where  t1.ID=t2.ID order by t1.ID;
```

If IsPresent is 0, then

```
select mark,age from table2;
```

ie. if entry is present in a table, i need to join else i don't need to join.

Is there any way we can achieve this with a single mysql select query?

Comment: You join `table1` but you don't show any columns from that table. Is that what you want? This may show duplicated data from `table2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can union the two different query cases which would look like:

```
SELECT T2.MARK, T2.AGE
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
WHERE
  T1.ID=T2.ID AND
  T1.ID=1500
UNION
SELECT MARK, AGE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE
  NOT ID=1500
```

Comment: Thanks for your query. I am getting additional duplicate rows back. I don't think union will help.

Comment: Is the Table 1 record having an ID=1500 the only condition? If so then instead of nesting select statements you can just test for T1.ID=1500 and NOT T1.ID=1500 in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT t2.mark, t2.age
    FROM table2 t2
      JOIN table1 t1
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE EXISTS
          ( SELECT *
            FROM table1
            WHERE id=1500
          )
  UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.mark, t2.age
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT *
            FROM table1
            WHERE id=1500
          )
```

which can be simplified to:

```
    SELECT t2.mark, t2.age
    FROM table2 t2
      LEFT JOIN table1 t1
        ON  t1.id = t2.id
        AND EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM table1
              WHERE id=1500
            )
```